# Constants are not "populated" when including a PHP file from remote server

Tags: php, include, constants, remote-server

I have the folowing issue: I got a PHP file (`standards.php`) with statements like these:

```
define('CONSTVAR', '/path/');
```

Now, I have another file called `untitled.php`, containing this:

```
include ('standards.php');
echo CONSTVAR;
```

This will result in a page saying `/path/`, the value of the constant.

It's good so far.

But when I put the `standards.php` on another one of my websites and try to include it from there (using the `include('http://mysite.eu/core/standards.php');` command), it doesn't work. The constant remain empty, and I also get the following error

> Warning: main(http://mysite.eu/core/standards.php) [function.main]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/this.nl/core/untitled.php on line 28
>
> Warning: main() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://mysite.eu/core/standards.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php4/lib/php') in /home/www/this.nl/core/untitled.php on line 28

`allow_url_include` is enabled and `allow_url_fopen` too. When I type the full URL of the `standards.php` into my browser, I get a page result, so it's not an issue of not having access rights, right?

What could be the issue here? Why is the constant, which is supposed to be global, not "inherited" when including from a remote server?

Comment: What is in your included file?
Does it have PHP tag around it?
You must echo the content you need. If you have constants defined within PHP tags, nothing arrives at the other server.
Simply visit the includefile from a webbrowser to see what it returns

Comment: The problem is not with constants, it's with the external `include`. The include failed of course, so the file was not *include*-ed.

Comment: ha..... I just saw this comment. `upped` ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Allow_url_include is enabled and allow_url_fopen too. When I type the
>   full url of the standards.php into my browser, I get a page result, so
>   its not an issue of not having access rights, right?

`allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` can only be set in php.ini or httpd.conf. It is the local server that is preventing the file from being included, which is different to typing the URL into the browser.

> Why is the constant, which is supposed to be global, not "inherited"
>   when including from a remote server?

Even if the external include worked, it won't work as expected. Includes over HTTP are different to standard includes.

You are including the *output* of the included file. The External PHP file is processed at the external server before being included.

It would certainly be a security vulnerability if external PHP files could be read verbatim in this way.

Comment: allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are enabled, but I understand that the remote server processes the php file first? that's a pity..

its still strange that it gives me a permission denied error, even if the file to be included can be opened in a browser..

Comment: @BobHasgould: The "permission denied error" is a warning message from the local PHP server. There is something in the local server configuration that is preventing this. The request is not even getting to the remote server by the looks. Specifying the file directly in the browser is obviously bypassing any local PHP server. (I'm using the term 'local' to refer to the source server from which you are making the requests, which may or may not be local to your machine.)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot usually `include` PHP files from remote hosts over the `HTTP` wrapper because when your PHP parser requests the include, it either fails to find the file (`include` is used to include files from the local filesystem with absolute or relative paths), or the remote webserver sends it not the *source code*, but a parsed PHP file like it would send to a browser. And `include` takes source code.

For further information, taken from the manual entry of [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> **Warning. SECURITY WARNING:**
>
> Remote file may be processed at the remote server (depending on the file extension and the fact if the remote server runs PHP or not) but it still has to produce a valid PHP script because it will be processed at the local server. If the file from the remote server should be processed there and outputted only, readfile() is much better function to use. Otherwise, special care should be taken to secure the remote script to produce a valid and desired code.

Answer (score 4):

```
function cthulhu_include($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $code = curl_exec($ch);

    eval($code);

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Delivering. Also make sure that you have for example .txt (plain text) file instead of .php (processed plain text) (because you will get blank output), that way everyone can see your code in the process, too.

Comment: I like your function name. But still I'd warn @BobHasgould to refrain from relying on remote includes, let alone the leaky `eval()` command. There is no sense in loading your scripts from an external source. Well... there **is**, but only rely on it if it's impossible to do otherwise, better-wise.

Comment: No, there is no sense in loading it via HTTP. If he doesn't want to listen (numerous advices have been given), then he'll learn from his mistakes. Hopefully, he will change his architecture (if any).

Comment: I know this is not a "desirable architecture" and it's not intended as a permanent solution, its merely an experiment!
Not sure what the above code is supposed to do but it doesn't result in anything. the code I include is a php file, and this factor cannot be changed.

Comment: @BobHasgould: The above code gets around having to enable `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` and the permission denied warning you seem to be getting.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** usually advisable to use external includes.

They do not usually work well (or at all).

So don't use external includes.

Comment: @WesleyMurch well they could, if the file that is included is raw PHP. but if the php page is already translates, then it will **not** work.

Comment: I'm sorry, "raw PHP"? I'm pretty sure you can `include` any type of file, maybe you should flesh out your answer a bit more. EDIT: OK, I see what you mean, but it's not well explained in your answer.

Comment: plain text which contains unprocessed valid PHP code, he meant... but that is including files Cthulhu way.

Comment: @Neal It will if the PHP script outputs valid PHP code. And I have seen this used in a misguided attempt to set up virtual hosting, the effects of which were... interesting. A more salient point is that it won't work unless `allow_url_include` is switched on, which in any half-way sane hosting environment it won't be.

Comment: @DaveRandom cURL + eval() :) (I've seen it.)

Comment: @webarto I love the smell of gaping security holes in the morning. You wouldn't believe the number of times I've seen `eval()` used where `call_user_func_array()` is all that was required.

Comment: Guys, first off, I know the implications of using this, and its just a temporary solution.